# a issue with datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the datatables as mentioned in this link

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

now my table is 5 columns.

The issue is that, the 2nd column has got very lengthy names.

This multi filter shows options at the bottom of table.

Now I have a problem. Since my 2nd column has got very lengthy names, so the bottom "option" cell below that column is very lengthy making the table column going out of html page.

How can i reduce that "bottom" column?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what you mean with "bottom" column, but i can tell you i had the same problem with jquery-datatables.

Solution 1: Add scrollbar to the div containing the datatable so if it gets too much large it will not occupy all page.
like "overflow: auto".

Solution 2: make all the parents containing the datatable with auto height(no fixed height) to allow the page to extend as far as the datatable take space.

PD: you can increase the width of the column 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set fixed layout for your table as below:

```
table{
   table-layout:fixed;
}
```

That's it.